# http server don't want to start

Tags: apache, webserver, devserver

(http server is "Apache 2.4.25 x86 - PHP 5.6.30 x86")

Hi
I have installed this server (easyphp devserver) on a Windows 7 and I migrate to Windows 10.
All was Ok for weeks and suddenly the server don't want to start anymore.

When I click on the start button, and after hourglass cursor, the button stay green and show "Start".

Error Log file is empty.

Access log shows a strange message :

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36642816 bytes) in E:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2425vc11x86x171117163109\eds-app-dashboard.php on line 285
```

Is it looks like a VC problem ?

Can I reinstall DevServer without loosing my config ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem found :
Working with Hyper-V, it changes my network IP address.
Because this IP is used in http server configuration file, it crash when starting.